# SimpleCV error when call SimpleCV in python

Tags: python-2.7, simplecv

I installed simplecv super pack with Python. However when I run `from SimpleCV import ImageSet`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    from SimpleCV import ImageSet
ImportError: No module named SimpleCV
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible things that it could be.  Either it may not have installed correctly or your python path is not setup correctly.  I'm not sure what OS you are on (by the code output I'm guessing windows),

To verify it installed correctly do a search from the file explorer for 'SimpleCV' and see if it is found under the python libraries directory.  If so then it probably installed and then you just need to do:

```
SETX PATH C:/Python27/;C:/Python27/Scripts/;C:/OpenCV2.3/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/;%PATH%
SETX PYTHONPATH C:/OpenCV2.3/opencv/build/python/2.7/;%PYTHONPATH%
```

If that doesn't work you may have to install manually:
https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV#windows-7vista